# Открыть Bottom Sheet по нажатию на итем в recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview.adapter, bottom-sheet

Мне нужно открывать окно bottom sheet по нажатию на элемент в recyclerview. Recyclerview находится во фрагменте, и вызов **supportFragmentManager** затруднился. Как можно это реализовать?

**Мой recyclerview Adapter**

```
class UsersAdapter(private val videoTitles: List<String>, private val Trening: List<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val videoTitle = videoTitles[position]
        val Trening1 = Trening[position]
        holder.view.name.text= videoTitle
        holder.view.quantity.text= Trening1
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return videoTitles.size
    }



    class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
                Toast.makeText(view.context, "asd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }
            }


    }
    }
```

**BottomSheetFragment**

```
class mBottomSheepFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
     val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cording_layout,container, false)
    return v
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

}
```

}

Comment: Вообще, надо бы прокинуть интерфейс в холдер через адаптер и его в холдере вызвать, сам интерфейс в активити реализовав. Однако, если это сложно, то можно и просто скастовать контекст к-л вьюхи в холдере к активити - тогда будет  supportFragmentManager  доступен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете интерфейс подобно такому:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {

    fun onItemClick() // сюда можно передать нужные вам параметры, например позицию кликнутого item или сам item
}
```

Далее в адапетер:

```
class UsersAdapter(
    private val videoTitles: List<String>, 
    private val Trening: List<String>,
    private val clickListener: OnItemClickListener
): RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

    // остальной ваш код

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val videoTitle = videoTitles[position]
        val Trening1 = Trening[position]
        holder.view.name.text= videoTitle
        holder.view.quantity.text= Trening1
        // тут вы задаете ваш листенер
        holder.view.setOnClickListener { clickListener.onItemClick() }
    }
}
```

Далее в активити/фрагменте:

```
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity, OnItemClickListener {

    // some code

    private val usersAdapter = UsersAdapter (videoTitles, Trening, this) // логику создания можете перенести туда где вам это нужно

    override onItemClick() {
        // здесь вы открываете ваш BottomSheet
    }
}
```